# About multi args When using QCommandLineOption

Tags: qt

When I use `QCommandLineOption` and `QCommandLineParser` to parse, I cannot get multi args.

Here is what I want:

`dbmanager.exe -f args1 args2`

I want to get `args1` and `args2`. But I aways cannot get `args2`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

arg1 and arg2 look like positional parameters, that is arguments that your application expects to be given in a specific order.

This snippet of code should help you get what you want:

```
QCommandLineParser parser;
// define the parameters and options your application will use
parser.addPositionalArgument("arg1", QCoreApplication::translate("main", "this is the first argument."));
parser.addPositionalArgument("arg2", QCoreApplication::translate("main", "this is the second argument."));

// this is for the -f option
QCommandLineOption fOption(QStringList() << "f" << "foption",
        QCoreApplication::translate("main", "does something optional."));
parser.addOption(fOption);
```

Then check the parameters and the options given with the following:

```
// process command line arguments given by the user
parser.process(app); // app is your QCoreApplication instance

const QStringList args = parser.positionalArguments(); // arg1 is at 0 index, arg2 is at 1

// check the f option
bool foptionIsOn = parser.isSet(fOption);
```

To make the code more robust, you may want to check the number of positional arguments provided, and issue an error/warning if something is missing.